# Ghidra: Reading all registers contents at chosen instruction

Tags: debugging, ghidra, register

Remembering all register contents may be exhausting so I would like to find a solution to be able to see all register contents at a chosen instruction in the Listing. I know debuggers got this function when you set a breakpoint at the instruction you are interested in and move to it, you can see the contents of all registers but is there a way to integrate this functionality into Ghidra? Some kind of plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Ghidra is a *static* disassembler / decompiler, i.e., it is *not able to perform instructions.*

It means that there is no possibility to see the registers' values, to follow their changes, or to log them.

You need a **debugger** to reach it, such as [x64dbg](https://x64dbg.com/) or [IDA Pro](https://hex-rays.com/ida-pro/).

**EDIT:**

This answer is appropriate for Ghidra releases *up to 9.x.y* (I used 9.2.4 making this answer).
From release 10.0 Ghidra **has** a debugger (thanks [blabb](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/3473/blabb) for his note).

Comment: isnt it possible to somehow integrate the debugger into ghidra via some plugin?

Comment: ghidra has a debugger for last 2 3 releases

Comment: @blabb, thanks for your comment, I didn't know about it, now I upgraded to the latest release.

Comment: @REpro - for older releases of Ghidra (without a debugger) it is not possible. For now I how no experience with releases 10+, which have the debugger, I'm sorry.

Comment: @blabb how do I find it?